# How to create choropleth map with geojson and plotly dash

Tags: geojson, plotly-dash, choropleth

I'm attempting to create a map of English local authorities using plotly dash. I have a geojson file of the following format:

```
  'properties': {'NAME': 'Cheshire East (B)',
  'AREA_CODE': 'UTA',
  'DESCRIPTIO': 'Unitary Authority',
  'FILE_NAME': 'CHESHIRE_EAST_(B)',
  'NUMBER': 1,
  'NUMBER0': 1,
  'POLYGON_ID': 123504,
  'UNIT_ID': 43553,
  'CODE': 'E06000049',
  'HECTARES': 116635.738,
  'AREA': 0,
  'TYPE_CODE': 'AA',
  'DESCRIPT0': 'CIVIL ADMINISTRATION AREA',
  'TYPE_COD0': '',
  'DESCRIPT1': ''}
```

I have tried creating the map with the following code:

```
fig = px.choropleth(df, 
                    featureidkey='properties.CODE',
                    geojson=lower_tier_map, 
                    locations='ons_code', 
                    color='csp_2021',
                    color_continuous_scale='Viridis'
                   )
```

However, I get a blank figure, except for a colour bar.

I copied the example from here:
[plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/)

And I got the same problem, no map shown just a colour bar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your geojson file that would translate to being able to plot a map. The plotly example has the following format

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '0500000US01001',
  'STATE': '01',
  'COUNTY': '001',
  'NAME': 'Autauga',
  'LSAD': 'County',
  'CENSUSAREA': 594.436},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[-86.496774, 32.344437],
    [-86.717897, 32.402814],
    [-86.814912, 32.340803],
    [-86.890581, 32.502974],
    [-86.917595, 32.664169],
    [-86.71339, 32.661732],
    [-86.714219, 32.705694],
    [-86.413116, 32.707386],
    [-86.411172, 32.409937],
    [-86.496774, 32.344437]]]},
 'id': '01001'}
```

The most important part of the geojson file is the polygon coordinates. This is what informs plotly on constructing the actual map. In my personal experience, downloading a shapefile of the area and then converting the shapefile into geojson polygons is the easiest.

Comment: My fault, I snipped that bit out of the summary before posting, but it is in there. And converting a shapefile to geojson is exactly how I created it.

Comment: Okay could you update your answer with the polygon and I can take another look at it. Even better if you upload your geojson file I can run it myself.